# how to loop through array with dynamic keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array **data** where I am storing the result of an SQL query as below :

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($db,$sql);  
$data = [];
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
if(!empty($row)) { $data[] = $row; }  }
```

then I want to create a group key which is the concatenation of specific keys of my array **data** as below :

```
foreach ($data as $d) {

$group_key = $d['id'].'_'.$d['Country'].'_'.$d['Order Numer']; 

//rest of my code 

}
```

it works fine but I want to choose the keys dynamically instead of setting up  manually id, Country and Order Number...
let's say I have an array  `$PostKeys = ["id","Country","Order Number"];` this array will vary depending on the values selected by user...

What I did is :

```
$PostKeys = ["id","Country","Order Number"];

foreach ($data as $d) { 

  foreach($PostKeys as $value)
  { $array_group_key[] = $d[$value] ; }

$group_key = implode("_",$array_group_key); 
// rest of my code 
}
```

I am supposed to get the same result but there is always mismatch. I didn't figure out where is the issue exactly. Any suggestions please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the value of `$PostKeys`? What result do you get? Are you resetting `$array_group_key` before each sub-loop? Also, please reformat your code properly.

Comment: @Jeto  I formatted my code. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks, but not really, you should refer to https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#example for a good example of what most PHP projects follow. What about my other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to empty `$array_group_key` each time through the loop. Otherwise, you're appending to the results from all the previous rows.

```
foreach ($data as $d) { 
    $array_group_key = [];
    foreach($PostKeys as $value)
    { 
        $array_group_key[] = $d[$value] ; 
    }
}
```